# What are custom_css and customize_changeset used for?

Tags: core, post-type, post-type-support

A fresh wordpress install has the following post types:

- Post (Post Type: 'post')
- Page (Post Type: 'page')
- Attachment (Post Type: 'attachment')
- Revision (Post Type: 'revision')
- Navigation Menu (Post Type: 'nav_menu_item')
- Custom CSS (Post Type: 'custom_css')
- Changesets (Post Type: 'customize_changeset')

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types doesn't address what the final two are used for.

Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mentioned Post Types deal specifically with The Customizer.

## Custom CSS Post Type

The `custom_css` post type is used to store all themes "Custom CSS" content found in The Customizer under Additional CSS. Each theme gets it's own post ( whenever the Additional CSS is saved ) with the CSS stored as `post_content`. Then only the active theme's post is used when displaying the theme. We can see that in action via [`wp_get_custom_css_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_custom_css_post/). You may read more about this decision by checking out the Make Core post created by contributor [George Stephanis](https://profiles.wordpress.org/georgestephanis): [Extending the Custom CSS Editor](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/26/extending-the-custom-css-editor/).

## Changesets Post Type

This is a version of autosaves for The Customizer. You may read a more in-depth post by [Weston Ruter](https://profiles.wordpress.org/westonruter): [Customize Changesets Technical Design Decisions](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/10/12/customize-changesets-technical-design-decisions/)

> **The TL;DR for this post** is that customize changesets make changes in the customizer persistent, like autosave drafts. For users, the customizer tab can be closed and re-opened and the changes will persist. Users can make changes to one theme and switch to another in the customizer without losing the changes upon switching. A customizer session can be bookmarked to come back to later or this URL can be shared with someone else to review and make additional changes (the URLs expire after a week without changes). The new APIs make possible many new user-facing features in future releases and feature plugins, including saving drafts, submitting changesets as pending for review, scheduling changes, and more.

Comment: +1 for the info. I didn't notice the last 2 post types. Btw, the TL;DR was longer than the original post (Kappa).

Comment: Beat me to it, I had the same idea with these two Make posts ;-) It would be nice to mention the authors of these posts too.